# What is wrong with this "proof" that $a^q \equiv a \pmod n$ for any $a, q, n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I came across this while trying to prove this for a specific $n$ and $q$, but I knew it was wrong once it generalized to any $n$, it's simply too good to be true:

Let $\gcd (a, n) = d$. Then $d | a \implies d|a^q$, so

$$d|(a^q-a)$$

Also $d|n$, so there exist integers $k_1, k_2$ such that

$$k_1 \cdot d = a^q-a \tag{1}$$

$$k_2 \cdot d = n \tag{2}$$

So $(2)$ is equivalent to $d = \dfrac {n}{k_2}$. Substituting this in $(1)$,

$$k_1 \cdot \dfrac {n}{k_2} = a^q-a$$

$$ \dfrac {k_1}{k_2} \cdot n = a^q-a$$

Because the RHS is an integer and $n$ is an integer, $\dfrac {k_1}{k_2}$ is an integer, so

$$a^q \equiv a \pmod n$$

Comment: $\frac{k_1}{k_2}$ need not be an integer: the factors of $k_2$ not present in $k_1$ may be present in $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes thank you I realized my mistake

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you tend to comment/answer a minute or two before I do. (This has happened on a lot of questions). I just hope you know I am not copying your material!

Comment: @RSerrao I believe you were slightly faster than him this time haha

Comment: @RSerrao Indeed you were for sure, I just checked and I got the notification of the answer first

Comment: @RSerrao Oh okay :P

Comment: @RSerrao: Not to worry: I certainly never thought that. (And as Ovi says, you were actually ahead of me this time, though I didn’t realize it until after I posted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right when you say $k_1, k_2$ exist and are integers, but $\frac{k_1}{k_2} $ need not be integer from the things you know about them.

In particular, $a = 2, n = 5, q = 2 \Rightarrow k_1 = 1, k_2 = 5 \Rightarrow \frac{k_1}{k_2}  = \frac15$

Comment: Ah yes even though $\dfrac {k_1}{k_2} \cdot n$ is an integer,  ${k_1} /{k_2}$ need not be an integer :(

Comment: @Ovi exactly. A simple counter example was added in my answer